# fetch first N categories (dimensions of a variable) in SQL(ORACLE)

Tags: sql, oracle

Please help on the below query request. Thanks.

SQL Query from ORACLE 
Fetch the data for first 100(any N) Categories(Dimensions) at one time. And next can be next time. This is to control the data size
EG: Fetch the data for FACTORS from ABCD to HIJK at one time. Remaining 2 at next time etc.

```
EG: Table
ID  FACTORS VALUE
1   ABCD    100
2   ABCD    101
3   ABCD    102
4   ABCD    103
5   ABCD    104
6   DEFG    105
7   DEFG    106
8   DEFG    107
9   DEFG    108
10  DEFG    109
11  DEFG    110
12  HIJK    111
13  HIJK    112
14  HIJK    113
15  HIJK    114
16  HIJK    115
17  HIJK    116
18  MNOP    117
19  MNOP    118
20  MNOP    119
21  MNOP    120
22  MNOP    121
23  99-1    122
24  99-1    123
25  99-1    124
26  99-2    125
27  99-2    126
```

Comment: you should you rownum https://blogs.oracle.com/oraclemagazine/on-rownum-and-limiting-results

Comment: Hi ,Rownum or limit function give by rows. if letsay select 1:100 rows I might miss some of the rows belongs to one category(dimension variable)..Thats the reason seeking other options.

Comment: And given the data above, what would be the expected answer?

Comment: Fetch the data .. Eg if counter=3 .. First 3 factor(dimension or categories) A:HIJK's corresponding data to be retrived.. Please help Thanks

Answer (score 0):

1. You could simply use `>=` and `<=` like:

   ```
   SELECT *
          FROM ELBAT T
          WHERE T.FACTORS >= 'ABCD'
                AND T.FACTORS <= 'HIJK';
   ```

   (Put an index on `FACTORS` to support that.)
2. If it has to be numeric you could rank the rows using the `RANK()` window function:

   ```
   SELECT *
          FROM (SELECT T.*,
                       RANK() OVER (ORDER BY T.FACTORS) R
                       FROM ELBAT T) X
          WHERE X.R >= $n
                AND X.R <= $m;
   ```

   (`$n` and `$m` are the numeric bounds, replace them with the respective literals. And again an index on `FACTORS` might help.)
3. You could also mimic the ranking without using the `RANK()` window function by using (correlated) subqueries:

   ```
   WITH CTE
   AS
   (
   SELECT DISTINCT
          T.FACTORS
          FROM ELBAT T
   )
   SELECT *
          FROM ELBAT T
          WHERE T.FACTORS >= (SELECT C1.FACTORS
                                     FROM CTE C1
                                     WHERE (SELECT COUNT(*)
                                                   FROM CTE C2
                                                   WHERE C2.FACTORS <= C1.FACTORS) = $n)
                AND T.FACTORS <= (SELECT C1.FACTORS
                                         FROM CTE C1
                                         WHERE (SELECT COUNT(*)
                                                       FROM CTE C2
                                                       WHERE C2.FACTORS <= C1.FACTORS) = $m);
   ```

   (`$n` and `$m` are the numeric bounds, replace them with the respective literals. And again an index on `FACTORS` might help.)

   If you actually got a table with the distinct factors, replace the CTE with it. In that case the mimiced rank *might* perform better than the one using the window function.

Comment: Thanks Saxon,Sticky bit. I will try them tomorrow. @Sticky bit, In Point 2 Query Can I replace $n , $m with 1 and 100 to get first 100 (100 is eg number) FACTORS.In my case having 10000+ distinct Factors there I cannot go by some factor name thats the reason asked.   Please help .. Thanks

Comment: @stats03: Yes, that's how I intended `$n` and `$m` to work.

Comment: Thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
SELECT a.id, a.factors, a.value FROM elbat a, (select t.factors, rank() over (order by t.factors) as "ord" FROM elbat t) b WHERE a.factors = b.factors AND b.ord > = $start AND b.ord <= $end;
```

Comment: Hi Saxon Thanks  I tried the above query it seems working.. But is there any way I can get ORD as 1,2,3,4 rather than any odd sequence.(as my each factor had different number of rows ORD for each factor become 1,92,200,354 etc)

Comment: SELECT a.id, a.factors, a.value FROM elbat a, (select distinct t.factors, dense_rank() over (order by t.factors) as "ord" FROM elbat t) b WHERE a.factors = b.factors AND b.ord > = $start AND b.ord <= $end;There was a missing distinct